# Why is -[UISearchBar showsScopeBar] ignored?

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uisearchbar

As long as `-[UISearchBar scopeButtonTitles]` is not `nil`, the search bar displays its scope bar no matter whether I set `showsScopeBar` to `YES` or `NO`. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me.  It only showed up for me after switching my storyboard from AutoLayout to the prior layout method.  With AutoLayout on, it hides it.  With it off, it shows it and I have to set them to be nil.

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the `scopeButtonTitles` property to `nil` to hide scope bar :

```
searchbar.scopeButtonTitles = nil;
```

Comment: Solved my problem